# .htaccess bloqueando o $_GET na URL

Tags: php, regex, htaccess

Fiz uma rota no .htaccess para criar uma URL específica. Mas agora não estou conseguindo pegar os elemento que vem direto do $_GET da URL.

Minha rota é

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Eu tenho a seguinte URL

```
livros/?status=10&msg=1
```

Não estou conseguindo pegar o **status** e **msg** que vêm direto da URL. Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua regra de reescrita não encaminha os argumentos da query string, use QSA:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Agradeço muito a ajuda. Era isso.